# Converting keys and values of a multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have the following PHP array:

```
$data = array(
    'data' => array(
        'first_key' => 'first_value',
        'second_key' => 'second_value',
        'third_key' => 'third_value',
        'fourth_key' => array(
            'mini_first' => 'mini_value'
        )));
```

I need to apply filters to the keys and values. For simplicity's sake, I need to convert to uppercase and add another character:

```
$data = array(
    'DATA' => array(
        'FIRST_KEYx' => 'FIRST_VALUEx',
        'SECOND_KEYx' => 'SECOND_VALUEx',
        'THIRD_KEYx' => 'THIRD_VALUEx',
        'FOURTH_KEYx' => array(
            'MINI_FIRSTx' => 'MINI_VALUEx'
        )));
```

Suppose you don't know how many array levels the array will have. How can I solve this?

Comment: `foreach`, `array_walk`, `array_map`. go try something

Comment: I tried array_walk_recursive, which would make sense since there is a no limit restriction. However, array_walk_recursive only works on leaf nodes, and I need to change all the keys. And some inner keys hold arrays... I wouldn't be asking if I didn't try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is right:

```
<?php


$data = array(
    'data' => array(
        'first_key' => 'first_value',
        'second_key' => 'second_value',
        'third_key' => 'third_value',
        'fourth_key' => array(
            'mini_first' => 'mini_value'
        )));



function convert($array){

$new = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){

        $new[strtoupper($key)."x"] = convert($value);
    }else{

        $new[strtoupper($key)."x"] = strtoupper($value)."x";
    }
}

return $new;

}


print_r(convert($data));
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/L9Pow1

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[strtoupper($key) . "x"] = strtoupper($value) ."x";
}
$data = $newArray;
```

Comment: need to add a check for mult-dimensions and make it recursive, but this would be my basic approach

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying use this

```
$input_array = array("FirSt" => 1, "SecOnd" => 4);
print_r(array_change_key_case($input_array, CASE_UPPER));
```